# Count the number of occurance of a value in a column for an object

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

Problem statement- Users can have any number of notifications. Need to count the number of notification he has and print with SQL query. Below is the sample table.

```
+---------------------------------+
|  primary_number | notification  |
+---------------------------------+
| ----------------+-------------- |
|  88             | mwi           |
|  88             | mwi           |
|  87             | mwion         |
|  87             | mwioff        |
|  89             | mwi           |
| (5 rows)                        |
+---------------------------------+
```

Fyi, if you see the table, in primary number table 88 have two mwi notification no mwion no mwioff. Therefore, in result set, it should print primary number as 88, number of mwi as 2, number of mwion as 0 and number of mwioff as 0 with the select statement.

Expected output::

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+ |
| | primary_number | Number_of_mwi | number of mwioff | number of mwion | |
| +----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+ |
| |             88 |             2 |                0 |               0 | |
| |             87 |             0 |                1 |               1 | |
| |             89 |             1 |                0 |               0 | |
| +----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+ |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve">Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example</a>

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Fyi, if you see the first table, in primary number table 88 have two mwi notification no mwion no mwioff. 

Therefore, in result set, it should print primary number as 88, number of mwi as 2, number of mwion as 0 and number of mwioff as 0 with the select statement.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557. I will take care this from now onwards.

Comment: Are `mwi`, `mwion` and `mwioff` the only possible values for `notification`, or is it completely dynamic?

Comment: mwi, mwion and mwioff are the only possible values. It is not dynamic.

Comment: @Mureinik if it is dynamic? What would be the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's `filter` clause for aggregate functions (`count`, in this case), is just the tool for the job:

```
SELECT   primary_number,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE notification = 'mwi') AS num_of_mwi,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE notification = 'mwion') AS num_of_mwion,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE notification = 'mwioff') AS num_of_mwioff
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY primary_number
```

Comment: I appreciate. Thank you very much. Will be exploring more the clauses now.